# How to fix "Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2, uwsgi

I deployed my django application with `sqlite3`, `uwsgi emperor mode` and `python v3.6.7` on `ubuntu 18.04`
Now I changed database to `postgresql`, every thing worked fine in my local machine, but in the server when I run `uwsgi server.ini` (for testing purpose) I get this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

and application just shows "Internal Server Error" in the browser.

- **I can import `psycopg2` in the python shell without any error**
- `psycopg2` is installed in my virtualenv
- I installed `python-psycopg2` using apt-get too
- django will run without any problem using `python manage.py runserver`
- I did not use `sudo` with `pip` to install `psycopg2`
- django `settings.py` configs are right, because I performed migrations

I read all similar problems and tried their answers, nothing worked :(

Comment: I read than answer, the problem is that I can import psycopg2 in python shell

Comment: Are you sure that the shell is using the same environment.

Comment: Yes, I used `virutalenv wrapper` and I open python shell while virtualenv is enabled @Sayse

Comment: @Sayse: How does one figure out whether the shell is using the same environment?